# How to retrieve the one particular lwc component (only one) from org to vs code?

Tags: lightning-web-components, deployment, salesforce1-app, vs-code, manifest

We all know that it is possible to retrieve all the lwc components from org to vs code using the manifest file but I need to just get only one lwc component from org. Is there any way to do so please share.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use manifest file to retrieve one component as well

Answer (score 1):

Click on the org browser which is of cloud logo in VS code, there you can select the LWC component and select the corresponding LWC component the one you want to download

Comment: Hi, Can you be more specific on this process? I don't see a cloud logo in my install of VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

The cloud icon is called org browser which  displays the available metadata types and their corresponding components in your default org. You can use this to retrieve particular components which you need from the org. I have attached a snippet for your reference.

Note: Org Browser is available only in non source-tracked orgs such as sandboxes or Developer Edition orgs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command from terminal to get a single LWC component. In the below command, `helloWorld` is the LWC component name.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m LightningComponentBundle:helloWorld
```